# Default priority of Task.detached

Tags: swift, actor, thread-priority

When you create a detached task with [detached(priority:operation:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856786-detached) but leave `priority` set to nil, what priority does iOS assign?

For example, suppose a photo output handler calls an actor like this:

```swift
class PhotoViewController: UIViewController {
    func photoOutput(_ photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        let photoWithContext = someCallToMainActor(photo)
        Task.detached {
            let result = async someCallToAnotherActor(photoWithContext)
            async anotherCallToMainActor(result)
        }
    }
}
```

The docs for detached(priority:operation:) say about priority, “You need to handle these considerations manually with a detached task.” Since the detached task isn’t a child task, I don’t get the feature that, “Child tasks inherit the parent task’s priority”.

I realize that I can specify the priority explicitly. Still, there presumably is a reason that detached(priority:operation:) allows priority to be nil, and one would expect a well defined semantic. Are there any rules that govern the detached task’s priority?

Comment: Why not just look to see what this task's priority _is_? At least that way you'll know what priority is assigned in _this_ case.

Answer (score 0):

For child tasks the priority of task is inherited from parent task, and for both detached task and a parent task if priority provided is `nil`, [`TaskPriority.medium`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskpriority) is used as priority.

Answer (score 0):

**TL&DR;** Detached tasks with no specified priority end up having the `.medium` priority, at least this holds true at the time of writing this answer. Things can change in the future, however not sure how likely is for this one to change.

---

One of the many nice things about Swift is that it's open source, so we can take a look and see what happens under the hood.

If we take a look at the [Task.detached()](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fde58da/stdlib/public/Concurrency/Task.swift#L621) implementation we can see the following code:

```swift
public static func detached(
  priority: TaskPriority? = nil,
  operation: __owned @Sendable @escaping () async -> Success
) -> Task<Success, Failure> {
#if compiler(>=5.5) && $BuiltinCreateAsyncTaskInGroup
  // Set up the job flags for a new task.
  let flags = taskCreateFlags(
    priority: priority, isChildTask: false, copyTaskLocals: false,
    inheritContext: false, enqueueJob: true,
    addPendingGroupTaskUnconditionally: false)
```

The priority gets passed to the [taskCreateFlags()](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fde58da/stdlib/public/Concurrency/Task.swift#L438) function, which currently looks like this:

```swift
func taskCreateFlags(
  priority: TaskPriority?, isChildTask: Bool, copyTaskLocals: Bool,
  inheritContext: Bool, enqueueJob: Bool,
  addPendingGroupTaskUnconditionally: Bool
) -> Int {
  var bits = 0
  bits |= (bits & ~0xFF) | Int(priority?.rawValue ?? 0)

  ...
}
```

So, in case the `priority` argument is nil, the first byte of the task flags, which represent the priority, will be zero.

Now, if we continue digging, we reach the compiler area, and at some point we'll reach to [Task.cpp:755](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fde58da/stdlib/public/Concurrency/Task.cpp#L755), which reads

```cpp
if (isUnspecified(basePriority)) {
   basePriority = JobPriority::Default;
}
```

, and so happens that [JobPriority::Default](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fde58da/include/swift/ABI/MetadataValues.h#L2224) corresponds to the value `0x15`, which, coincidentally or not, and as others have noticed, correspond to the `.medium` task priority.